# How can I find rows in MySQL where a name has a column=1, but doesn't exist another row with the same name, but has no column=2?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example:

```
name | age
Joe     21
Ben     21
Joe     26
```

I want names where age is 21, but not 26. In this example, Ben should be the only result. I'm not even sure where to start. Can anyone provide insight on this? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: `WHERE name NOT IN (...)` What do you think should be inside `(...)`?

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed. No need to be condescending. I already mentioned I wasn't sure where to start. Not to mention what you're suggesting can be gamed just by an asker providing some blatantly wrong attempt and claiming that is what they've already tried.

Comment: Didn't mean to be condescending, that was intended as a leading question.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the "StackOverflow is not a free coding service...". But thanks for your help. Your use of Socratic method worked.

Comment: That's just a boilerplate comment, used by many people here.

Answer (score 0):

try this one using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select * from table t
where age = 21
and not exists (
select 1
from table x
where x.name = t.name
where age <> 21
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the names, you can do:

select name

```
from t
group by name
having sum( age = 21 ) > 0 and
       sum( age = 26) = 0;
```